# How do I pass a prop from a Parent styled component to its children's styled components no matter how deep

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, react-props

I have these styled components:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => props.theme === "light" ? "hsl(0, 0%, 98%)" : "hsl(235, 24%, 19%)" };
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: ${props => props.theme === "light" ? "0px 35px 50px -15px rgba(194, 195, 214, 0.5)" : "0px 35px 50px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" };
`

const Footer = styled.footer`
  padding: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: ${props => props.theme === "light" ? "hsl(236, 9%, 61%)" : "hsl(234, 11%, 52%)" };
  font-size: 14px;
`

const Nav = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: inherit;
`

const NavItem = styled.a`
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  color: inherit;

  &:hover {
    color: ${props => props.theme === "light" ? "hsl(235, 19%, 35%)" : "hsl(236, 33%, 92%)" };
  }

  &:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  ${({ active }) =>
    active &&
    css`
      color: hsl(220, 98%, 61%);
    `
  }
`

const ClearList = styled.p`
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    color: ${props => props.theme === "light" ? "hsl(235, 19%, 35%)" : "hsl(234, 39%, 85%)" };
  }
`
```

And I have this component called `TodoList` with a `theme` props that get passed to the styled components like this:

```
const TodoList = ({ theme }) => {
  return (
    <Container theme={theme}>
      <Footer theme={theme}>
        <p>5 items left</p>
        <Nav>
          <NavItem theme={theme}>All</NavItem>
          <NavItem theme={theme}>Active</NavItem>
          <NavItem theme={theme}>Completed</NavItem>
        </Nav>
        <ClearList theme={theme}>Clear Completed</ClearList>
      </Footer>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default TodoList
```

How do I call the `theme` props only once in the `Container` element and make it accessible to all the child elements such as Clearlist, NavItems and Footer without explicitly passing them

Thank you

Comment: You don't need. Using styled-components Provider and defining a theme to them, the theme props will be available inside your styled.element``.  The way you are doing is redundant.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and someone answered it for me here:
Long story short is that props don't cascade down in that way, using a Theme can resolve this by keeping the var at a global level
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65887861/passing-props-through-nested-styled-components

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by using ThemeProvider

visit this link https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced

Example

```
// Define our button, but with the use of props.theme this time
const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${props => props.theme.fg};
  border: 2px solid ${props => props.theme.fg};
  background: ${props => props.theme.bg};

  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;

// Define our `fg` and `bg` on the theme
const theme = {
  fg: "palevioletred",
  bg: "white"
};

// This theme swaps `fg` and `bg`
const invertTheme = ({ fg, bg }) => ({
  fg: bg,
  bg: fg
});

render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <div>
      <Button>Default Theme</Button>

      <ThemeProvider theme={invertTheme}>
        <Button>Inverted Theme</Button>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```